# for what value of $k$ does the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^k} dx$ converges? and what is the value of the integral for that $k$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

i've been working this problem and only got this far
using substitution $u=\ln x$ i got
$$I = \int_0^\infty u^{-k} du$$
making
$$I = \frac{u^{1-k}}{1-k}\bigg\vert_0^\infty $$
$$I = \frac{1}{1-k}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[a^{1-k}+0^{1-k}\right]$$
i've figure out that for $k<1$ or $k>1$ the integral diverges, but i'm not sure about $k=1$.

Comment: I think you actually used the substitution $u=\log x$.

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^k} dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^k} d(\ln x)=\frac{(\ln x)^{1-k}}{1-k}|_1^\infty$$
And:
$$\lim_{k\to 1^+} \frac{(\ln x)^{1-k}}{1-k}=-\infty\\
\lim_{k\to 1^-} \frac{(\ln x)^{1-k}}{1-k}=+\infty$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{k\to 1} \frac{(\ln x)^{1-k}}{1-k}=\infty$$
So, the integral diverges for $k=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{1}^{+\infty}u^{-k}\,du$ is convergent iff $k>1$ and $\int_{0}^{1}u^{-k}\,du$ is convergent iff $k<1$, so the given integral is never convergent. At $k=1$

$$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\left[\log\log x\right]_{a}^{b}.$$